# Why does vanitygen warns me to update an up-to-date OpenSSL?

Tags: vanitygen

I tried to generate an address with vanitygen. Because I'm on a MBP 2010 it took a while onthe CPU (not finished yet, two times up to 20%) and now I am trying to get it working with my GPU (NVidea 330m). That works, it is three times as fast as the CPU (±750 kkeys/s vs 230 kkeys/s), but I have a question about the OpenSSL.

When I start oclvanitygen `./oclvanitygen -d 1 -i 1Mathias` it gives me the following warning:

```
WARNING: Built with OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
WARNING: Use OpenSSL 1.0.0d+ for best performance
```

However, `openssl version` gives me this:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
```

And `sudo port upgrade openssl` returns also that there is nothing to be done. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you compile oclvanitygen yourself (on 5 Feb 2013), or get the binary from somewhere?  It may have been compiled (or be statically linked) with a different version than the one you currently have installed.

Comment: I built it myself, yesterday. The source is however not updated in 2 years (https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen)

Comment: A quick glance at the source shows that it checks the `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` macro, which comes from the header `openssl/opensslv.h`.  I suspect you have an old version of openssl (or at least its headers) installed somewhere.

Comment: I do got an old HDD with an installation from 2011/2012. The last time I booted from there (and probably updated) was a year ago, june 2013. So that IS a possibilities, that it takes the OpenSSL from there.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [WyseNynja's Homebrew tap](https://github.com/WyseNynja/homebrew-bitcoin), you can then install `vanitygen` with better dependency handling.